# How to load extensions into SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate, aggregate-functions, standard-deviation

I need a standard deviation function in SQLite. I have found one here:

http://www.sqlite.org/contrib?orderby=date

but its part of an extension file to SQLite. I've never installed one of these before and I don't know how to. I found this existing function, *load_extension*, at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html, but I don't understand what the parameters X and Y are.

Basically, I need someone to give me a step by step guide on how to install the aggregate extension file. Can anyone do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SQLite extensions are libraries with dynamic linkage. You can find some examples [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160923215223/http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru:80/wiki?name=extensions) (This is a [fossil](/questions/tagged/fossil) repository, click on “login/fill captcha” to enable hyperlinks). See for example [md5.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20130617133439/http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/artifact/316d730b4c55d1124328953c9b2ac54b4041df2f).

- `load_extension` must be enabled in SQLite (pragma IIRC)
- it requires as first argument the path of the library
- The second argument is the name of the entry point function (in md5.c it is `sqlite3_extension_init`). Its prototype must be `int(sqlite3*, char **, const sqlite3_api_routines *)`.
- In SQL you can try `SELECT load_extension('md5.so', 'sqlite3_extension_init');` or simply `SELECT load_extension('md5.so');`

You can try to compile `md5.c`, and from the sqlite shell use `.load md5.so`

Comment: I am currently having a similar question. I am trying to execute SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite') in sqlite, I have the corresponding mod_spatialite.dll - file, but I can't get it to work. Where do I need to put the .dll-file?

Comment: @user3116232 Are you using full path to the .dll in load_extension() statement? If so, try not to do so. I realised that the deduction of extension entry point name is not working with Windows-style paths.

Comment: @user3116232 i have the same problem. how you solved it?

Comment: @user3116232 Same problem here! Any resolution?

Answer (score 7):

You can follow [loadext.html](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html):

1. Download the `.c` file of the extension
2. Compile the `.c` file locally using commands from Section 3, "Compiling A Loadable Extension" in [loadext.csv](https://www.sqlite.org/loadext.html) (check a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969377/how-to-compile-sqlite3-extension-csv-virtual-table/) if you have compilation errors)
3. Load the library via `sqlite3_load_extension(PATH)` (`.load PATH` in the CLI or `SELECT load_extension(PATH)` in queries), where `PATH` is a relative or full path to the compiled library, preferably *without* filename extension for compatibility reasons (i.e., `.load csv`, not `.load csv.dylib` or whatever extension your system adds)

For `extension-functions` on MacOS, it would be:

```sh
curl --location --output extension-functions.c 'https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25'
gcc -g -fPIC -dynamiclib extension-functions.c -o extension-functions.dylib
```

Testing the extension:

```sql
SELECT load_extension("extension-functions");
CREATE TABLE test(x REAL);
INSERT INTO test (x) VALUES
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4),
  (5);
SELECT stdev(x) FROM test;
```

Expected output: `1.58113883008419`

Also Larry Brasfield at sqlite.org [explains](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/eaeb3e12f4) where you can put the compiled library to make it accessible across the system:

> If you provide an absolute path in the .load command or to the
>   sqlite3_load_extension() call, or to the load_extension() SQLite
>   function from SQL (when extension loading is enabled), then the
>   extension specified by that path will be loaded (if it can be.)
>
> If you want to name the extension to one of the load mechanisms
>   without an absolute path, then you must arrange that the compiled
>   extension can be located by the search that dlopen(...) conducts. That
>   can vary, but usually it examines directories specified by an
>   environment variable, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, in the order listed by its
>   colon-separated values left-to-right, then /lib and /usr/lib.
>
> So, you can put your extension somewhere already searched, or you
>   could use the "env" command to launch the SQLite CLI with a modified
>   value for $LD_LIBRARY_PATH that includes where you put the extension.
>   Or you might simply modify that environment variable for a session in
>   which you are using the CLI. (This can lead to subtle problems, so be
>   sure you understand the potential effects going into that.)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a detailed guide on how to [install a SQLite extension](https://antonz.org/install-sqlite-extension/), but here is a TLDR (1-2 are about getting the extension, 3-7 are about loading it into SQLite):

1. You can find a pre-compiled extension for your operating system (aka "package") in the [SQLite package registry](https://sqlpkg.org/).

The standard deviation function is available in the `nalgeon/stats` package.

2. Alternatively, you can download a `.c` file and compile it using `gcc`:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared extension.c -o extension.so
```

3. For SQLite CLI (`sqlite3.exe`), use the `.load` command (I'll use the `stats` extension as an example from here on):

```
.load /Users/anton/Downloads/stats
```

4. For SQLiteStudio, SQLiteSpy, DBeaver and other similar tools, use the `load_extension` function:

```sql
select load_extension('/Users/anton/Downloads/stats');
```

5. For Python, use the default `sqlite3` module:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.load_extension("/Users/anton/Downloads/stats")
conn.execute("select median(value) from generate_series(1, 99)")
conn.close()
```

Alternatively, use the [`sqlean.py`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean.py) package.

6. For Node.js, use the [`better-sqlite3`](https://github.com/WiseLibs/better-sqlite3) package:

```js
const sqlite3 = require("better-sqlite3");
const db = new sqlite3(":memory:");
db.loadExtension("/Users/anton/Downloads/stats");
db.exec("select median(value) from generate_series(1, 99)");
db.close();
```

7. For Go, use the [`mattn/go-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) package:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    sqlite3 "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    sql.Register("sqlite3_with_extensions",
        &sqlite3.SQLiteDriver{
            Extensions: []string{
                "/Users/anton/Downloads/stats",
            },
        })

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3_with_extensions", ":memory:")
    db.Query("select median(value) from generate_series(1, 99)")
    db.Close()
}
```

And that's it!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete way to do this on Windows:

1. Install MinGW with GCC
2. Download the .c file of wanted extension (for example [uuid.c](https://sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc/uuid.c))
3. Download from [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) **Source Code** and **Precompiled Binaries for Windows**
4. Put files from **"sqlite-dll-win64-x64-XXXXXXX.zip"** (or win32) and **"sqlite-tools-win32-x86-XXXXXXX.zip"** to the System32 folder
5. Put wanted **uuid.c** file and files from **"sqlite-amalgamation-XXXXXXX.zip"** to any folder you want to
6. Run CMD and go to the folder with **uuid.c** file
7. Type `gcc -g -shared uuid.c -o uuid.so`
8. If someone (even yourself) told you that on Windows you should use **.dll** extension, spit in this person's face
9. Shove the resulting **.so** file into the folder System32
10. Run CMD again and type `.load uuid` OR type `SELECT load_extension('uuid')` as SQL script

***You're done here!***

[@James Kerfoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576178/james-kerfoot), I mention you as my "contemporary". So, you have to compile .c file into **.so** and put into the System32 folder

Comment: It absolutely doesn't have to have `.so` extension in Windows -- `.dll` is absolutely fine, and you absolutely don't need MinGW or GCC to compile it, Visual C++ compiler does an excellent job.