# How to use the carray loadable extension in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am attempting to use the **carray** loadable extension in the sqlite3 shell but I get the dreadful message: `Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I don't know if this is an sqlite issue or something else. I have already read through the official docs and several related SO questions (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663124/how-to-load-extensions-into-sqlite)), but according to these resources it *appears* that I'm already doing everything right.

I've downloaded the [carray](https://www.sqlite.org/src/raw/ext/misc/carray.c?name=40c27641010a4dc67e3690bdb7c9d36ca58b3c2d) source code, and [compiled](https://sqlite.org/loadext.html) it successfully with MSVC. The compile options are shown here, including the path to `sqlite3ext.h` and `sqlite3.h` in "\src":

```
cl carray.c /I..\src /link /dll /out:carray.dll
```

This generates: `carray.dll`, `carray.obj`, `carray.lib`, and `carray.exp`.

With the sqlite3 shell started in the same directory as the compiled code, I get the following errors - trying a few different ways to load the compiled extension:

```
C:\SQLite\src\ext>sqlite3
SQLite version 3.16.2 2017-01-06 16:32:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.

sqlite> .load carray                           ----- Try without the extension.
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

sqlite> .load carray.dll                       ----- Oh, I should use the extension.
Error: The specified module could not be found.

sqlite> .load ./carray                         ----- OK...maybe? Nope.
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./carray.dll'); ----- Time to ask SO.
Error: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried recompiling using different options to specify the system architecture, but I get the same errors. Any hints?

*System Details: SQLite 3.16.2, Windows 10 64-bit, MS Visual Studio 14 (2015)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried compiling `carray` with `cl carray.c /I..\src /link /dll /out:carray.dll` like you did. And `.load carray` works for me without a problem.

I'm using the command line tool downloaded from http://sqlite.org/download.html (The sqlite3.exe is a 32-bit application.)

Maybe you are using the `cl` for x64 and a 32-bit version of `sqlite3.exe`? Try using "Develoepr Command Prompt for VS2015" instead of "VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt". So `where cl` prints something like `...\bin\cl.exe` instead of `...\bin\amd64\cl.exe`.